# How do I fix inconsistent types in InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb

In InfluxDB (1.5), I have a table where the fields have become inconsistently typed. Most rows in the table are Integer, however, some rows have become strings.

1. How is this possible? I thought, once a field's types were set (upon first insert), any insert into the table with incorrect typing would fail.
2. What do I do now? If I go back and attempt to overwrite the data in the inconsistent rows, I get errors saying the field is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research, here's what I've discovered:

Answer to Part 1:

InfluxDB uses a system they refer to as 'sharding' - while I don't know the specifics, I do know that data from the same measurement/table can be stored across multiple, different 'shards'.

According to the InfluxDB documentation, field types can differ between these shards, within the same field, on the same table.

Answer to Part 2:

In order to fix this, the [currently-suggested answer](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/tldr-influxdb-tech-tips-december-01-2016/) is to make a new table, download all the data, and re-insert while ensuring the data that gets inserted is the proper types.

If you had a tag which changed type and became a field, this can be especially difficult to fix, the link above does not address that. To do selects only on tag or field, you can use `tag_name::tag` or `field_name::field` within a select statement.

The `GROUP BY *` clause suggested in the link is required in order to preserve tags, but seemed to cause issues when I used it.

My current solution is a PHP script that uses curl, downloads the points, chunks them, then re-inserts the points into the new table, ensuring each point that gets inserted is casted to the new, uniform type, and properly inserted.

The best way to stopping future issues, is simply not to have them. I went looking for how to lock field types in all cases, across all shards, for a particular measurement table.

Unfortunately, it seems impossible to guarantee 100% type consistency across all current and future shards. "Don't make mistakes because it's really difficult to clean up" seems to be InfluxDB's modus operandi.

Comment: I edited this comment to follow the question structurally. I will also be updating the answer as I get more effective at managing InfluxDB.